# Entity Framework Code First Migrations - Can I target previous migration

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am using migration.exe with CCNet to update the database on deployment, I am wondering if there is a way to roll back that change if I decide to roll back the published version.

I know there is a way to target the original version: $InitialDatabase, and also way to target a named migration TargetMigration:"AddPostAbstract". But the name of the migration target will change on each deployment.

Is there any way to target the previous migration, regardless of it's name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rollback in this case will be manual task otherwise you will most probably need to create some custom action which will check target database's `__MigrationHistory` table and find the name of target migration.

`$InitialDatabase` is just powershell variable and its value is 0. When working with powershell you can create your own custom `$Previous` variable and fill it with some custom powershell script loading migration name from the database.